# Need to Add Another While in the below query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the below code from one of the experts here in this forum (Which is working fine). So what I'm trying to do is to amend this query further to get the dates the same way but for all tasks. There is a table called "TASK" in the database and each task_id has a clndr_id and proj_id. The desired output would be (proj_id, task_id, clndr_id, date_Value), so I think we need to add another WHILE to get all dates for all tasks in the TASK table. I hope @CurseStacker or anyone else can help :)..thanks.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetProjectDates] 
(   
     @project_name  varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @temp_tb TABLE([proj_id] int, [clndr_id] int , [date_value] date)
AS
BEGIN 
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    DECLARE @project_id int
    DECLARE @clndr_id   int
    DECLARE @walker     int             =   0
    DECLARE @holder     varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @date       date
    DECLARE @data       varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @project_id = [p].[proj_id]
          ,@clndr_id = [p].[clndr_id]
          ,@holder = [c].[clndr_data]
    FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[PROJECT] AS [p]
    INNER JOIN [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] AS [c] ON [p].[clndr_id] = [c].[clndr_id]
    WHERE [p].[proj_short_name] = @project_name

    WHILE @walker <> LEN(@holder) + 1
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 2) = 'd|'
        BEGIN
            SET @data = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 10)
            IF SUBSTRING(@data, LEN(@data) - 2, 3) = ')()'
            BEGIN
                SET @date = DATEADD(D, CAST(SUBSTRING(@data, 3, 5) AS int) -2, '01/01/1900')
                INSERT INTO @temp_tb VALUES (@project_id, @clndr_id, @date)
            END
        END
        SET @walker = @walker + 1
    END

    RETURN
END

GO
```

So "TASK" table includes (proj_id, task_id, clndr_id) and from "Calendar" table we can get the clndr_data by linking to proj_id in task table (The above code gets the dates in clndr_data between 'd|' and ')()' for only one clndr_id, and it works fine' Now I need to do the same but for several calendars;

```
proj_id task_id clndr_id    clndr_data
4917    310449  7143    (0||CalendarData()(.....
4917    310450  7144    (0||CalendarData()(.....
4917    310451  7149    (0||CalendarData()(.....
```

Desired Outcome (Assuming clndr_id 7143 has only 2 dates between 'd|' and ')()', clndr_id 7144 has 3 dates, and cldnr_id 7149 has two dates) JUST AN ASSUMPTION

```
proj_id  task_id clndr_id      date 
4917    310449   7143        2018-09-24
4917    310449   7143       2018-09-25
4917    310450   7144       2018-09-26
4917    310450   7144       2018-10-01
4917    310450   7144       2018-10-02
4917    310451   7149      2018-10-03
4917    310451   7149       2018-10-04
```

Comment: @CurseStacker, I hope you could help :)

Comment: Although this may work and looks very ugly, can you edit your post, show some lines of sample data showing what data in each table and what you want as expected final output.  Masking dates from multiple tables?  Indicating your original post that got you the help for this answer might already have the underlying data, but not the new table you are looking to get further assistance with.

Answer (score 0):

try something like below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetProjectDates] 
(   
     @project_name  varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @temp_tb TABLE([proj_id] int, [task_id] int, [clndr_id] int , [date_value] date)
AS
BEGIN 
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    DECLARE @project_id int
    DECLARE @task_id   int
    DECLARE @clndr_id   int
    DECLARE @walker     int             =   0
    DECLARE @holder     varchar(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @date       date
    DECLARE @data       varchar(MAX)

    declare @tab table (project_id int, task_id int, clndr_id int, holder varchar(max))

    insert into @tab
    SELECT [T].[proj_id] as project_id
          ,[T].[task_id] as task_id
          ,[c].[clndr_id] as clndr_id
          ,[c].[clndr_data] as holder
    FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[TASK] as [T]
    INNER JOIN [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] AS [c] ON [T].[clndr_id] = [c].[clndr_id] and [T].[Proj_id] = [c].[proj_id] 
    WHERE [T].[proj_id] = (select proj_id FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[PROJECT] where [proj_short_name] = @project_name)

    declare @cur_task int, @cur_clndr int
    set @cur_task = (select top 1 task_id from @tab)
    set @cur_clndr = (select top 1 clndr_id from @tab where task_id = @task_id)
    set @holder = (select top 1 holder from @tab where task_id = @task_id)

    while ((select count(1) from @tab) > 0)
    begin
        print 'Current loop running for Task_Id' + convert(varchar(10), @cur_task)
        WHILE @walker <> LEN(@holder) + 1
        BEGIN
            IF SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 2) = 'd|'
            BEGIN
                SET @data = SUBSTRING(@holder, @walker, 10)
                IF SUBSTRING(@data, LEN(@data) - 2, 3) = ')()'
                BEGIN
                    SET @date = DATEADD(D, CAST(SUBSTRING(@data, 3, 5) AS int) -2, '01/01/1900')
                    INSERT INTO @temp_tb VALUES (@project_id, @task_id, @clndr_id, @date)
                END
            END
            SET @walker = @walker + 1
        END

        delete @tab where task_id = @cur_task

        set @cur_task = (select top 1 task_id from @tab)
        set @cur_clndr = (select top 1 clndr_id from @tab where task_id = @task_id)
        set @holder = (select top 1 holder from @tab where task_id = @task_id)

        set @walker = 0
    end

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried your query but got the following error: Could not find stored procedure 'temp_tb'. Is there something I need to change? Thanks

Comment: there is no syntactical error in the code. (@)temp_tb is table variable (check if you are using it correctly), also check if you are using (@)return_tb or (@)temp_tb. can you please share the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: thanks again for the reply, I copied your code and tried to run the query again, I got this message: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. I don't know the difference between temp_tb and return_tb, this is not my background so apologies for not fully understanding your comment. thanks again.

Comment: I tried the new code but it keeps on executing without any output. I've updated my question if you want to check again, many thanks

Comment: Please check if you are getting correct records in the table @tab inside the function as we are looping through that table only. Also, can provide the sample records from the table dbo.TASK?

Comment: this would be the correct table:
    SELECT [T].[proj_id] as project_id
          ,[T].[task_id] as task_id
          ,[T].[clndr_id] as clndr_id
          ,[c].[clndr_data] as holder
      FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[TASK] AS [T]
     INNER JOIN [PMDB].[dbo].[CALENDAR] AS [c] ON [T].[clndr_id] = [c].[clndr_id] and [T].[Proj_id] = [c].[proj_id]
     WHERE [T].[proj_id] = (select proj_id FROM [PMDB].[dbo].[PROJECT] where [proj_short_name] = @project_name)

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer as per your comment. Please see if @tab is populating correctly now.

Comment: I've tried the code but again it's not working, it keeps executing for a more than a minute so I stop the query. I checked tab table and it's populating correct data but it seems that the loop is not working

Comment: I have added the print statement to check whether the loop is running fine or not and also set @walker to zero after completion of each inner loop. Please run it again and see if the loop is traversing all the task_ids from the tab.

Comment: It's not working again it keeps executing and when I stop I get this message: (4 row(s) affected)
Current loop running for Task_Id310452

(0 row(s) affected)
Current loop running for Task_Id310452

(0 row(s) affected)
Current loop running for Task_Id310452